# Looping though column in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I  am trying to import all the data from MS project to Excel using VBA in Excel.

```
Set aProg = appProj.ActiveProject

appProj.OutlineShowAllTasks
j = 2
For Each t In aProg.Tasks
    If (Not t Is Nothing) Then
Cells(j, 5).Value = t.Start
Cells(j, 6).Value = t.Task Name
Cells(j, 7).Value = t.%complete


j =j+1
end if
```

next

The code works fine if the column name/field name is not having any special character or blank.
Could anyone please let me know how we can refer field name with blanks or special characters like "t.Task Name" or "t.%complete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Early Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115) so you have [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)) when you are writing your code. That way you declare `t As MSProject.Task` and when you type `t` followed by a period you get a drop-down list of properties and methods.

For your specific case, the properties you want are `t.TaskName` and `t.PercentComplete`.